# Plotting Q-Q graph in Python like in R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

Ive´a trouble when I try to plot the following data store in variable i.

```
   Dates
2015-08-21    0.032369
2015-08-24    0.040211
2015-09-01    0.030023
```

Python

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = sm.qqplot(i, line='45')
plt.show()
```

R

```
r <- 0.01
spcs <- as.numeric(diff(time(i)))
qq_plot(spcs, FUN = function(p) qexp(p, rate = r)) # r = exceedance probability
```

in R

I get the following plot:

[image: QQ_PLOT in R]

I share the link to the notebook in colab may be help to understand the problem

[Colab Link][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should plot the index of the `pandas` series instead (take the diff of the `DatetimeIndex`, convert it to `timedelta` and extract days), like the following, in order to get the correct qq-plot (with the appropriate distribution):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(i.index), unit='ns').days.values
# array([3, 8])

r = 0.01
fig = sm.qqplot(pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(i.index), unit='ns').days.values, \
                stats.expon, loc=0, scale=r)
plt.show()
```

[image]